# Add category mean value to faceted scatter plots in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am using facet wrap to plot Weight Gain versus Caloric Intake for four different diets. Diet is a four-level factor, Weight Gain and Caloric Intake are numeric. I am adding a regression line to each plot facet. What I want to do is add a horizontal line for the group mean weight gain for each diet in the plot (4 different mean values). The problem is when I use the geom_hline function it puts the global mean on all of the plots, which is not what I want.

I tried using stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="line"), but it gives me line segments joining each of the points in every plot.

Below is the code I am using that is giving me the single global mean on all plots. Also the data set I am using.  I've included the labeller code for completeness but I really just need help with drawing the group mean lines.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
# Calculate slopes and means to use for facet labels
#
wgSlope<-rep(NA,nlevels(vitaminData$Diet))
dietMeans<-rep(NA,nlevels(vitaminData$Diet))
for (i in 1:nlevels(vitaminData$Diet)){
  dietMeans[i]<-mean(filter(vitaminData,Diet==i)$WeightGain)
#
# Get regression lines and coefficients for each facet 
#
lm<-lm(WeightGain~CaloricIntake,data=filter(vitaminData,Diet==i))
wgSlope[i]<-lm$coefficients[2]
}
#
# Build facet labels
#
dietLabel<-c(`1`=
               paste("Diet 1, Slope=",round(wgSlope[1],2),", Mean=",round(dietMeans[1],1)),             
             `2`=paste("Diet 2, Slope=",round(wgSlope[2],2),", Mean=",round(dietMeans[2],1)),             
             `3`=paste("Diet 3, Slope =",round(wgSlope[3],2),", Mean=",round(dietMeans[3],1)),
             `4`=paste("Diet 4, Slope =",round(wgSlope[4],2),", Mean=",round(dietMeans[4],1)))
#
# Draw the plots
#
ggplot(data=vitaminData,
           aes(y=WeightGain,x=CaloricIntake,color=Diet))+
theme_bw()+
geom_point(aes(color=Diet,fill=Diet,shape=Diet))+
  geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE,linetype=2,alpha=0.5)+
    labs(x="Caloric Intake",y="Weight Gain")+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue","orange","darkgreen"))+
  geom_hline(yintercept=mean(vitaminData$WeightGain))+
  facet_wrap(~Diet,labeller=labeller(Diet=dietLabel))+
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

```
 Diet  WeightGain CaloricIntake
   <fct>      <dbl>         <dbl>
 1 1             48            35
 2 1             67            44
 3 1             78            44
 4 1             69            51
 5 1             53            47
 6 2             65            40
 7 2             49            45
 8 2             37            37
 9 2             73            53
10 2             63            42
11 3             79            51
12 3             52            41
13 3             63            47
14 3             65            47
15 3             67            48
16 4             59            53
17 4             50            52
18 4             59            52
19 4             42            45
20 4             34            38
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using `dplyr`. (Add `library(dplyr)` or `library(tidyverse)` if not already loaded.)

```
  geom_hline(data = vitaminData %>% 
               group_by(Diet) %>%
               summarize(mean = mean(WeightGain)),
             aes(yintercept = mean)) +
```

[image]